# App Center - Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to setup an android app with app center analytics and crashes.

I have followed the tutorial on their official website.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/android)

When I set the Log level to Log.Verbose I get App Center SDK configured successfully, but when the app runs I get the following error

The website it is trying to reach is  https://in.appcenter.ms/logs?api-version=1.0.0

I am running the app on emulator with Android 11. I see that when the app runs on api<21 people have run into this problem.

Also microsoft wouldnt be using an ssl certificate , so why does my app throw the above error.

Does this mean that I have to setup ssl to store aap centers certificate.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

````
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.```
````

Comment: What is your build gradle version? Is it over 4.1.0?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? If just started happening for me on Android 12 in a Xamarin solution

Comment: Same here! Xamarin Solution with AppCenter 4.5 and Android 12